# Assigning double to const int& vs int to const int&

Tags: c++, int, constants

I am trying to understand constant reference in C++ and I stumbled across this problem:

When I assign double to a const int& and then change the value of the referencing double, the value of my int reference stays constant.

```
    double i = 10;
    const int &ref = i;    
    i = 20;

    cout << "i: " << i << endl;      // i = 20
    cout << "&ref: " << ref << endl; // ref = 10
```

Whereas while assigning int, the value gets changed.

```
    int i = 10;
    const int &ref = i;    
    i = 20;

    cout << "i: " << i << endl;      // i = 20
    cout << "&ref: " << ref << endl; // ref = 20
```

What is the reason for this behaviour? My guess is that when assigning double, the implicit conversion to int creates a new object and its reference is then being assigned, however I can't find it written down anywhere.

Comment: The = there is not assignment, its initialization/construction.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am using g++ from Cygwin

Comment: @KubaSpatny sorry, I misread the assignments. Ignore my previous message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though it looks like, `ref` isn't a reference to `i`.

```
double i = 10;
const int &ref = i;   // ***
i = 20;
```

A reference to an `int` cannot refer to a `double`. Therefore, in the marked line, a conversion from a `double` to an `int` takes place and the result of conversion is a temporary rvalue. Normaly, they are destroyed when the full expression they were created in ends. But there's a rule in C++ that allows extending the lifetime of a temporary when it is bound to a reference to `const`. It is extended until the reference dies. For that, the compiler actually allocates some memory for it behind the scenes.

The assignment modifies the original object `i`, the unnamed temporary stays intact.

Comment: What is the reason for this behaviour? It looks quite dangerous and unpredictable, so I assume there must be something it's useful for.

Comment: That's the kind of explanation I was looking for :) Thank you!

Comment: @Kylotan For example, it allows writing `v.push_back( SomeClass(42) );`, where `v` is some container, without having to create a named object of `MyClass` and without needless copies.

Comment: @KubaSpatny No problem. I'd paste the normative text from the standard that describes this, but I forgot where exactly it is and it's getting late :)

Answer (score 4):

When you convert the `double` to an `int`, the result is an rvalue of type `int`. This temporary value is bound to a constant reference variable, and thus the lifetime of the temporary value is extended to that of the reference variable. Changing the original `double` has no effect on that.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler can help you a lot only if you remove `const` from both declarations and attempt to compile the code snippets:

```
double i = 10;
/*const*/ int &ref = i;    //ERROR - WHY?
```

This code will give compilation error! Why?

But this code:

```
int i = 10;
/*const*/ int &ref = i;   //NO ERROR
```

will compile fine.

If the first code compiles fine when there is `const`, why doesn't it compile now (when `const` is not there)? What is going on under the hood?

Well, the reason is, actually `int&` is a reference type which can refer to an *object* of type `int` only, not `double`, so a temporary object of type `int` is created out of the expression`i` (which is `double`), but the temporary object cannot bind to `int&` , so it gives *compilation error*, but as soon as you put `const` there, it compiles fine, because a temporary object of type `int` can bind to `const int&`.

No such thing happens in the second code — no temporary object is created. So when you set `i` to `20`, the `ref` also changes in the second case (as it refers to `i`) but in the first case, when you set `i` to `20`, the `ref` does **not** change because `ref` does **not** refer to `i` anymore — it rather refers to the temporary object (which you're **not** changing!). That explains the behaviors of your code snippets.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.. Coming from Java, I find many things that are done differently but it's quite hard to see them all.

Answer (score 0):

```
double i = 10;
const int &ref = i;
```

Depending on the compiler you are using this code, as is, could as well give a compilation error.

On a compiler where it throws an error, if you cast it to `(int &)` you would see undefined behavior, since you are reading an int from a double's location. 
On a compiler which accepts this line, my best guess is it is creating a temporary variable (an rvalue) and assigning to the int reference, and any changes to the original variable are not reflected in the reference.

For the reference to work make sure the source data type can be represented by destination data type.

Answer (score -1):

You can think of an int as a class, and int(double); as a way of constructing an int from a double, you have a const reference to that int, which was constructed from a double.